# How feature communicate with eachother in wspbuilder project?

Tags: web-part, wspbuilder

Suppose i have multiple features inside my wspbuilder. That includes a list definition, and a webpart.

1. I want to fetch the records / items inside list, into my webpart. how we can do this ?
2. As i explained , i have a list definition in my WSPBuilder project. the requirement is, to set the lookup field on that list itself on ID Or Title column. Can we do this ? What i have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) object. But you should develop what you want to do. There is often native components that can do the job with a small amount of work
2. either use the [AddLookupMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.addlookup.aspx), or do the stuff in the list definition. The later way is quite hard, because the list definition schema is not always properly handled by SharePOint code. I also have to add, that the lookups needs to be used with precaution. You have to create the target list, then the child list (can't create the lookup on a non existing field)

Comment: Thanks for reply Steave B, I would also use SPQuery. I have more interest in programming itself not in xml stuffs. But i observe as i added blank feature in WSPBuilder project, i got there reciever class with some events structure. which event is suitable to define the list definition and set the lookup field ?

Comment: I use to add the lookup in the feature receiver that create the child list instance.

Comment: ok, Which event is suitable to create list definition

Comment: sorry, I meant list definition, not list instance. the idea is to monitor the feature activated event (the feature with the list definition), and add the lookup from this event

Comment: ok so sequence will: in Feature Activated event , create the custom list and once it get created add lookup field in same event. right? What should do on FeatureInstalled event ?

Comment: you can create the custom list through a ListInstance definition in a feature. FeatureInstalled is fired when the feature is deployed in the farm. Useful when you have to modify something once per farm